# Using foreach for an array contained in an object on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, foreach

I have an array that displays like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [count] => 3 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [receipt_id] => 126422362 [order_id] => 123068049....
```

I would like to print ONLY the receipt_id from each of the results of the array (0,1,2). How would I do that using a `foreach`?

I tried this:

```
foreach($result2 as $openOrders) 
    {
    echo $result2->results[]->receipt_id;
    }
```

but not working.

Comment: You have not array. You have object

Comment: @AlmaDo: He has an array of objects.

Comment: @AmalMurali I've started reading. So I see `stdClass Object ...` - it isn't an array

Comment: Well, I've started reading from string's start (which will point to whole structure data type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

For each iteration `$order` becomes an object you need (has property `receipt_id`).

```
foreach($result2->results as $order){
    echo $order->receipt_id;
}
```

Comment: not working. The way I print 1 result is like this: echo $result2->results[0]->receipt_id;

Comment: I got it, try updated code.

Comment: That's good. Thanks. Will set you as right answer!

Comment: Deleted my answer and upvoted this as correct